# Responsive image shrink

Tags: html, css

I have somewhat of a dilemma right now with responsive images. Right now, the amount of images shown per pixel is correct, however the images seem to shrink tremendously. Is there something I can do to fix this?

```css
img {
  max-width: 200%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}


/* Section Inner */

div.section-inner {
  max-width: 1100px;
  height: auto padding: 0 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Body Content */

div.body-content {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
}


/* Thirds */

div.thirds {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

div.one-third {
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

div.one-third-last {
  margin: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  div.one-third {
    width: 30%;
  }
  div.one-third-second {
    margin: 0;
  }
  div.one-third-last {
    margin: 0;
  }
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

div.nav ul li {
  width: 25%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bababa;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div.nav ul li {
    width: 33%;
  }
  div.one-third {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  div.one-third-second {
    margin: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  div.nav ul li {
    width: 33%;
  }
  div.one-third {
    width: 33%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  div.one-third-second {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- header -->

<!-- body-content -->
<div class="body-content">
  <div class="section-inner">
    <!-- thirds -->
    <div class="thirds clearfix">
    
      <!-- one-third -->
      <div class="one-third mobile-collapse">
        <figure>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1100x800" alt="China" width="1000" height="750">
          <figcaption>Chinese_Dragon</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <!--/one-third-->
      
      <!-- one-third -->
      <div class="one-third one-third-second mobile-collapse">
        <figure>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1100x800" alt="Gringotts" width="1000" height="750">
          <figcaption>Gringotts_dragon</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <!--/one-third-->
      
      <!-- one-third -->
      <div class="one-third one-third-last mobile-collapse">
        <figure>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1100x800" alt="Hydra" width="1000" height="750">
          <figcaption>Hydra</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="one-third one-third-last mobile-collapse">
        <figure>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1100x800" alt="Ice" width="1000" height="750">
          <figcaption>Ice_dragon</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="one-third one-third-last mobile-collapse">
        <figure>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1100x800" alt="Monday" width="1000" height="750">
          <figcaption>The "I_Hate_Mondays" Dragon</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="one-third one-third-last mobile-collapse">
        <figure>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1100x800" alt="Sassy" width="1000" height="750">
          <figcaption>Sassy_Dragon</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <!--/one-third-->
      
    </div>
    <!--/thirds-->
    <!-- two-columns -->
  </div>
</div>
<!--/body-content-->

<!-- footer -->
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. What is your desired outcome and how does it differ from your current outcome? You mentioned the images seem small but it's unclear what you expect/want them to do/be, instead.

Comment: I found out what I did wrong. I am sorry if I phrased it wrong. I am new coding and this website. Sorry if my wording may be off.

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer.